# Criar apenas a relação muito para muitos em Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, modelo-relacional

Tenho um relacionamento muito para muito com as entidades yell e category:

model yell.rb

```
class Yell < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :yells
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

  def as_json(options={})
    super(:only => [:id, :title, :desciption, :price, :payment_type, :yell_type],
          :include => {
              :categories => {:only => [:id, :name]},
              :user => {:only => [:id, :name]}
          }
    )
  end
end
```

model category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :yells

  def as_json(options={})
    super(:only => [:id, :name],
          :include => {
              :yells => {:only => [:id, :title]}
          }
    )
  end
end
```

migrate create_categories_yells_join_table.rb

```
class CreateCategoriesYellsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories_yells, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :category, index: true
      t.belongs_to :yell, index: true
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :categories_yells
  end
end
```

Com isso eu fiz um metodo `crete` onde ele vai criar meu `yell` e criar a `category` caso ela não exista e cria o relacionamento entre os dois. E caso a `category` já exista é para apenas criar o relacionamento.

Então faço a seguinte chamada `POST`:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/yells
{
    "user_id":"1",
    "title":"mouse",
    "desciption":"rato",
    "yell_type":"demanda",
    "price":"20,00",
    "categories":[{"name":"tecnologica"}]
}
```

e ele chama meu metodo `create` no controller_yells.rb:

```
def create
  #@yell = Yell.new(yell_params.except(:categories))
  @yell = Yell.new({title: params[:title], desciption: params[:desciption], price: params[:price], user_id: params[:user_id], yell_type: params[:yell_type]})

  Array(params[:categories]).each do |rel|
    @category = Category.find_by_name(rel[:name])
    if @category
      #cria apena o relacionamento entre a category e o yell
    else
      @yell.categories.build(name: rel[:name]) #creates the relationship and category
    end
  end

  if @yell.save
    render json: {status: 0, message:"sucess", data: @yell}, status: :created
  else
    render json: @yell.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

ele cria tranquilo tudo certinho, mas não sei o que colocar no lugar do comentário `#cria apena o relacionamento entre a category e o yell`.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso ou alguma solução mais elegante?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir fazer isso tive de criar um model para minha tabela de join:

model category_yell.rb

```
class CategoriesYell < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :yell
end
```

e meu metodo create ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
def create
  #@yell = Yell.new(yell_params.except(:categories))
  @yell = Yell.new({title: params[:title], desciption: params[:desciption], price: params[:price], user_id: params[:user_id], yell_type: params[:yell_type]})

  if @yell.save
    Array(params[:categories]).each do |rel|

      @category = Category.find_by_name(rel[:name])

      if @category
        @categories_yells = CategoriesYell.new(category_id: @category.id, yell_id: @yell.id)

        if @categories_yells.save
          @yell.categories.build(id: @category.id, name: rel[:name])#only creates the relationship
        else
          render json: {status: 1, message:"relationship categoy not create", data: @yell.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end

      else
        @yell.categories.create(name: rel[:name]) #creates the relationship and category
      end

    end

    render json: {status: 0, message:"sucess", data: @yell}, status: :created
  else
    render json: {status: -1, message:"error", data: @yell.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

end
```